# Mule 4 different behavior in transactions flow between "run" and "debug" executions

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mulesoft, mule-esb

I have a very basic `ALWAYS_BEGIN` JMS flow with `LOCAL` transaction in Mule 4 that exhibits different behavior when I run it using the "run" or "debug" options of Anypoint Studio.

In the flow I'm listening to a JMS queue (ActiveMQ) using local transactions and inside this flow there is a DB update. This update is set with transaction option `NOT_SUPPORTED`. The reason I'm using this configuration is that the DB operation cannot join the transaction unless I set up `XA` transactions, and I just don't need this DB operation to join the ongoing transaction.

Flow code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:bti="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/bti"
    xmlns:ibm-mq="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ibm-mq"
    xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms" xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core"
    xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/bti http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/bti/current/mule-bti-ee.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/current/mule-jms.xsd http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ibm-mq http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ibm-mq/current/mule-ibm-mq.xsd">

    <db:config name="Database_Pool" doc:name="Database Config" doc:id="3976285e-04a2-47c9-9255-e2e86b950d1b" >
        <db:oracle-connection host="${db.host}" port="${db.port}" user="${db.user}" password="${db.password}" serviceName="${db.name}">
            <db:pooling-profile maxPoolSize="${db.pool.max}" maxIdleTime="30"/>
        </db:oracle-connection>
    </db:config>
    <jms:config name="jmsConfig" doc:name="JMS Config" doc:id="f2abf6aa-918f-4b92-b2fc-441264dacbb0" >
        <jms:active-mq-connection username="admin" password="admin" >
            <jms:factory-configuration brokerUrl="tcp://localhost:61616?jms.prefetchPolicy.all=1" />
        </jms:active-mq-connection>
    </jms:config>
    
    <configuration-properties doc:name="Configuration properties" doc:id="69522b3e-1ddb-4a8a-99c8-9f589c17cf67" file="configuration.properties" />
    <flow name="queue1Flow1" doc:id="5903e842-1d73-4cbb-ab18-539d9c139a74" >
        <jms:listener doc:name="On New Message" doc:id="6b9a1b13-be28-42c3-b738-a1d41fe20503" config-ref="jmsConfig" destination="q1" transactionalAction="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>
        <set-variable value="#[payload]" doc:name="Set Variable" doc:id="458cc4f4-8e50-4c4b-86cf-6f6434008b24" variableName="myVar"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="e5655210-8545-4804-9d6d-fcc8ba9c9961" message='"Message received"'/>
        <try doc:name="Try" doc:id="19ca29c9-94f1-4567-8f47-686b5aa60ea4">
            <set-variable value="#[payload]" doc:name="Set Variable 2" doc:id="fb1c34ec-46ae-4a6f-9558-001d586eea95" variableName="myVar2" />
            <db:update doc:name="Update" doc:id="16b72660-06e2-4a6e-92ba-f8b33c77d216" config-ref="Database_Pool" queryTimeout="5" transactionalAction="NOT_SUPPORTED">
                <db:sql><![CDATA[UPDATE PRODUCT SET CODE = 'UNKNOWN ITEM' WHERE ID = 9]]></db:sql>
            </db:update>
            <error-handler>
                <on-error-propagate enableNotifications="true" logException="true" doc:name="On Error Propagate" doc:id="868099d8-e5a9-4a60-be94-a1997636d3c0">
                    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="65841e83-aff5-485e-87a6-4067e77db029" message='"Database operation failed"' />
                </on-error-propagate>
            </error-handler>
        </try>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="c9aaa765-0c24-4754-9c2d-69c82d108329" message='"And we are done!"'/>
    </flow>

</mule>
```

When I debug the application the flow executes and at the end of the flow the JMS transaction is committed and the message is removed from the queue, and in the console logs I see there is an entry by class `org.mule.jms.commons.internal.connection.JmsTransactionalConnection` that indicates the JMS transaction is committed, followed by entries created by ActiveMQ that show how the transaction was indeed commited.

```
DEBUG 2021-03-08 11:28:38,655 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] [processor: ; event: ] org.apache.activemq.TransactionContext: Begin:TX:ID:LX334321-56133-1615220909403-3:1:1
DEBUG 2021-03-08 11:28:38,656 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] [processor: ; event: ] org.mule.jms.commons.internal.source.push.JmsMessageListener: Received message on session [Cached JMS Session: ActiveMQSession {id=ID:LX334321-56133-1615220909403-3:1:2,started=true} java.lang.Object@6d4a7e3a]
DEBUG 2021-03-08 11:28:38,657 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] [processor: ; event: ] org.mule.jms.commons.internal.source.push.JmsMessageListener: New Message: MessageID [ID:LX334321-60739-1615210727247-4:3:1:1:18]. CorrelationID []
DEBUG 2021-03-08 11:28:38,679 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] [processor: ; event: ] org.mule.jms.commons.internal.connection.session.JmsSessionManager: Binding transaction to current thread...
DEBUG 2021-03-08 11:28:38,679 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] [processor: ; event: ] org.mule.jms.commons.internal.connection.session.JmsSessionManager: Tx to bind: session: 'org.mule.jms.commons.internal.source.push.JmsListenerSession@5f036c0'
DEBUG 2021-03-08 11:28:38,688 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] [processor: ; event: ] org.mule.jms.commons.internal.message.JmsResultFactory: Creating Result: specification:[1.1], type:[ActiveMQTextMessage], contentType:[*/*], encoding:[UTF-8]
DEBUG 2021-03-08 11:28:38,688 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] [processor: ; event: ] org.mule.jms.commons.internal.message.JmsResultFactory: Message type received is: ActiveMQTextMessage
DEBUG 2021-03-08 11:28:38,817 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] [processor: ; event: ] com.mulesoft.mule.debugger.mule.notification.DebuggerPipelineMessageNotificationListener: Notification org.mule.runtime.api.notification.IntegerAction@728 was received 
INFO  2021-03-08 11:28:38,882 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] [processor: queue1Flow1/processors/1; event: ] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: "Message received"
DEBUG 2021-03-08 11:28:38,899 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] [processor: queue1Flow1/processors/2/processors/1; event: ] com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool: Testing PooledConnection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@266de0b] on CHECKOUT.
DEBUG 2021-03-08 11:28:38,965 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] [processor: queue1Flow1/processors/2/processors/1; event: ] com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool: Test of PooledConnection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@266de0b] on CHECKOUT has SUCCEEDED.
INFO  2021-03-08 11:28:39,203 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] [processor: queue1Flow1/processors/3; event: ] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: "And we are done!"
DEBUG 2021-03-08 11:28:39,221 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] [processor: ; event: ] org.mule.jms.commons.internal.connection.JmsTransactionalConnection: JMS Transaction Commit over Session [Cached JMS Session: ActiveMQSession {id=ID:LX334321-56133-1615220909403-3:1:2,started=true} java.lang.Object@6d4a7e3a]
DEBUG 2021-03-08 11:28:39,221 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] [processor: ; event: ] org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession: ID:LX334321-56133-1615220909403-3:1:2 Transaction Commit :TX:ID:LX334321-56133-1615220909403-3:1:1
DEBUG 2021-03-08 11:28:39,222 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] [processor: ; event: ] org.apache.activemq.TransactionContext: Commit: TX:ID:LX334321-56133-1615220909403-3:1:1 syncCount: 1
DEBUG 2021-03-08 11:28:39,224 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] [processor: ; event: ] org.mule.jms.commons.internal.connection.session.JmsSessionManager: Unbinding transaction from current thread...
```

But when I execute the same flow using the "run" option of Anypoint Studio the commit is never executed. The DB is updated, the last `logger` of the flow is executed but the transaction is never committed, and once I stop ActiveMQ the message is moved to the DLQ. running in this mode

```
DEBUG 2021-03-08 11:26:20,054 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] [processor: ; event: ] org.apache.activemq.TransactionContext: Begin:TX:ID:LX334321-56020-1615220768598-3:1:1
DEBUG 2021-03-08 11:26:20,055 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] [processor: ; event: ] org.mule.jms.commons.internal.source.push.JmsMessageListener: Received message on session [Cached JMS Session: ActiveMQSession {id=ID:LX334321-56020-1615220768598-3:1:2,started=true} java.lang.Object@5e1f53c1]
DEBUG 2021-03-08 11:26:20,055 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] [processor: ; event: ] org.mule.jms.commons.internal.source.push.JmsMessageListener: New Message: MessageID [ID:LX334321-60739-1615210727247-4:3:1:1:17]. CorrelationID []
DEBUG 2021-03-08 11:26:20,070 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] [processor: ; event: ] org.mule.jms.commons.internal.connection.session.JmsSessionManager: Binding transaction to current thread...
DEBUG 2021-03-08 11:26:20,070 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] [processor: ; event: ] org.mule.jms.commons.internal.connection.session.JmsSessionManager: Tx to bind: session: 'org.mule.jms.commons.internal.source.push.JmsListenerSession@65ebdf22'
DEBUG 2021-03-08 11:26:20,077 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] [processor: ; event: ] org.mule.jms.commons.internal.message.JmsResultFactory: Creating Result: specification:[1.1], type:[ActiveMQTextMessage], contentType:[*/*], encoding:[UTF-8]
DEBUG 2021-03-08 11:26:20,077 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] [processor: ; event: ] org.mule.jms.commons.internal.message.JmsResultFactory: Message type received is: ActiveMQTextMessage
INFO  2021-03-08 11:26:20,199 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] [processor: queue1Flow1/processors/1; event: ] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: "Message received"
DEBUG 2021-03-08 11:26:20,220 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] [processor: queue1Flow1/processors/2/processors/1; event: ] com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool: Testing PooledConnection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@6ed418b2] on CHECKOUT.
DEBUG 2021-03-08 11:26:20,287 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] [processor: queue1Flow1/processors/2/processors/1; event: ] com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool: Test of PooledConnection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@6ed418b2] on CHECKOUT has SUCCEEDED.
INFO  2021-03-08 11:26:20,505 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] [processor: queue1Flow1/processors/3; event: ] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: "And we are done!"
DEBUG 2021-03-08 11:26:20,522 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] [processor: ; event: ] org.mule.jms.commons.internal.source.push.JmsMessageListener: Waiting for message to be processed through flow
DEBUG 2021-03-08 11:26:20,522 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] [processor: ; event: ] org.mule.jms.commons.internal.source.push.JmsMessageListener: Resuming message consuming
```

Runtime

```
* Mule Runtime and Integration Platform                              *
* Version: 4.3.0-20210119 Build: 08e1da0d                            *
* MuleSoft, Inc.                                                     *
* For more information go to                                         *
* https://www.mulesoft.com/platform/soa/mule-esb-enterprise          *
*                                                                    *
* Server started: 3/9/21 5:31 PM                                     *
* JDK: 1.8.0_232 (mixed mode)                                        *
* JDK properties:                                                    *
*  - java.vendor = AdoptOpenJDK                                      *
*  - java.vm.name = OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM                         *
* - java.home =                                                      *
* C:\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.jdk.win32.x86_64_1.0.0. *
* 202004281356\jre                                                   *
* OS: Windows 10 -  (10.0, amd64)                                    *
* Host: LX334321 (180.123.44.126)                                    *
* Mule services:                                                     *
*  - api-gateway-contract-service-1.1.0                              *
*  - api-gateway-events-collector-service-1.1.0                      *
*  - mule-service-http-ee-1.6.8                                      *
*  - mule-service-oauth-ee-1.0.0                                     *
*  - mule-service-scheduler-1.3.2                                    *
*  - mule-service-soap-1.3.0                                         *
*  - mule-service-weave-ee-2.3.0-20210119                            *
* Mule server plugins:                                               *
*  - mule-agent-plugin                                               *
*  - mule-debugger-5.0.4-mule-server-plugin                          *
*  - munit-recording-server-mule-server-plugin                       *
* Applied artifact patches:                                          *
*  - APIKIT-2576-1.3.7-1.3.9-2.0.jar                                 *
*  - APIKIT-2612-1.0.0-1.0.2-1.1.0-1.0.jar                           *
*  - APIKIT-2612-1.1.1-1.0.jar                                       *
*  - APIKIT-2612-1.1.11-1.0.jar                                      *
*  - APIKIT-2612-1.1.12-1.2.0-1.2.2-1.0.jar                          *
*  - APIKIT-2612-1.1.13-1.1.14-1.2.3-1.2.4-1.0.jar                   *
*  - APIKIT-2612-1.1.15-1.1.16-1.0.jar                               *
*  - APIKIT-2612-1.1.2-1.0.jar                                       *
*  - APIKIT-2612-1.1.3-1.0.jar                                       *
*  - APIKIT-2612-1.1.4-1.0.jar                                       *
*  - APIKIT-2612-1.1.5-1.1.6-1.0.jar                                 *
*  - APIKIT-2612-1.1.7-1.0.jar                                       *
*  - APIKIT-2612-1.1.8-1.1.10-1.0.jar                                *
*  - APIKIT-2612-1.2.5-1.3.1-1.3.4-1.0.jar                           *
*  - APIKIT-2612-1.3.0-1.0.jar                                       *
*  - APIKIT-2612-1.3.5-1.3.9-1.0.jar                                 *
*  - APIKIT-2613-1.2.0-1.2.1-1.0.jar                                 *
*  - APIKIT-2613-1.2.2-1.0.jar                                       *
*  - APIKIT-2613-1.2.3-1.2.4-1.3.0-1.0.jar                           *
*  - APIKIT-2613-1.2.5-1.3.1-1.3.4-1.0.jar                           *
*  - APIKIT-2613-1.3.5-1.3.6-1.0.jar                                 *
*  - APIKIT-2613-1.3.7-1.3.8-1.0.jar                                 *
*  - APIKIT-2613-1.3.9-1.0.jar                                       *
*  - MULE-17706-1.1.1-1.1.2-1.0.jar                                  *
*  - MULE-17706-1.2.0-1.0.jar                                        *
*  - MULE-17706-1.2.1-1.2.2-1.0.jar                                  *
*  - MULE-17706-1.2.3-1.0.jar                                        *
*  - MULE-17706-1.3.0-1.3.1-1.0.jar                                  *
*  - MULE-17706-1.3.2-1.3.3-1.0.jar                                  *
*  - MULE-17706-1.3.4-1.0.jar                                        *
*  - MULE-17706-1.4.0-1.0.jar                                        *
*  - MULE-17706-1.4.1-1.4.3-1.0.jar                                  *
*  - MULE-17706-1.5.0-1.5.6-1.0.jar                                  *
*  - MULE-17706-1.5.10-1.5.11-1.0.jar                                *
*  - MULE-17706-1.5.7-1.5.9-1.0.jar                                  *
*  - MULE-18457-1.1.1-1.0.jar                                        *
*  - MULE-18457-1.2.0-1.2.1-1.0.jar                                  *
*  - MULE-18457-1.3.0-1.0.jar                                        *
*  - MULE-18457-1.3.1-1.0.jar                                        *
*  - MULE-18457-1.3.2-1.0.jar                                        *
*  - MULE-18457-1.3.3-1.0.jar                                        *
*  - MULE-18900-1.4.0-1.0.jar                                        *
*  - SE-12551-1.0.0-1.0.1-1.0.jar                                    *
*  - SE-12551-1.1.0-1.1.15-2.0.jar                                   *
*  - SE-12551-1.2.0-1.3.0-1.0.jar                                    *
*  - SE-12551-1.3.1-1.3.4-1.0.jar                                    *
*  - SE-12562-1.0.0-1.5.5-1.0.jar                                    *
*  - SE-17198-1.0.jar                                                *
* Mule system properties:                                            *
*  - mule.metadata.cache.expirationInterval.millis = 5000            *
*  - mule.testingMode =                                              *
* - mule.base =                                                      *
* C:\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.4.3.0.ee_7.3.5.2 *
* 02102051607\mule                                                   *
* - mule.home =                                                      *
* C:\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.4.3.0.ee_7.3.5.2 *
* 02102051607\mule                                                   *
*  - mule.forceConsoleLog =                                          *
*  - mule.metadata.cache.entryTtl.minutes = 10                       *
**********************************************************************
```

Libraries and connectors

```
**********************************************************************
* Started app 'project1'                                             *
* Application plugins:                                               *
*  - Database : 1.9.1                                                *
*  - IBM MQ : 1.6.4                                                  *
*  - JMS : 1.7.3                                                     *
*  - Sockets : 1.1.5                                                 *
*  - Spring : 1.3.5                                                  *
*  - XML : 1.3.0                                                     *
*  - HTTP : 1.5.21                                                   *
* Application libraries:                                             *
*  - ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar                                             *
*  - ucp-19.3.0.0.jar                                                *
*  - oraclepki-19.3.0.0.jar                                          *
*  - osdt_cert-19.3.0.0.jar                                          *
*  - osdt_core-19.3.0.0.jar                                          *
*  - simplefan-19.3.0.0.jar                                          *
*  - ons-19.3.0.0.jar                                                *
*  - com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.1.4.0.jar                                *
*  - bcprov-jdk15on-1.64.jar                                         *
*  - bcpkix-jdk15on-1.64.jar                                         *
*  - javax.jms-api-2.0.1.jar                                         *
*  - activemq-client-5.15.4.jar                                      *
*  - slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar                                            *
*  - geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar                                 *
*  - hawtbuf-1.11.jar                                                *
*  - geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar                     *
*  - spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar                                  *
*  - spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar                        *
*  - spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar                                    *
*  - spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar                                *
*  - spring-expression-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar                             *
*  - spring-security-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar                          *
*  - spring-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar                                   *
*  - spring-jcl-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar                                    *
**********************************************************************
```

Anypoint Studio
[image]

Comment: Please use XML text for the for the flow and configurations instead of images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason.
What are the Mule, Studio. database connector versions, and are you using any cumulative patch?

Comment: @aled edited the question to add additional details.

Comment: Thank you. Does the problem still happens if you remove the `<try>` and the database configuration?

Comment: @aled I've tried the following changes, and all of them result in the same issue: remove the `try` block and moving the `db:update` to the main flow, changing the db configuration to not make use of pooling. The only thing that seems to solve the issue is removing the `db:update` from the flow.